# How do I lerp a double or integer value in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I want to lerp the **elevation** property for a `Card` upon clicking and holding it on its `InkWell`.

What I want to do is change its **elevation** from say `50` to `0`, lerping it and reducing the value gradually the longer the `InkWell` is held, and when it is let go, it lerps back to `50` quickly.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: `Material` class animates some properties: one of them is `elevation` so all you need is to enlarge `animationDuration` to see that animation in action

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your specific question about lerping elevation, which is type double, there is a method in the dart ui package with the following signature:

```
double? lerpDouble(num? a, num? b, double t)
```

> Linearly interpolate between two numbers, a and b, by an extrapolation factor t.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/lerpDouble.html

Not sure this is necessary in your particular case but this is the exact answer to your exact question.

Edit:

Also, a cleaner solution to your problem would be to simply use a Material with type set to MaterialType.card since a) this is what the Card is "under the hood" and b) Material has an animationDuration parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Add a variable

```
double _updatedElevation = 50.0;
late Timer elevationTimer;
```

Then in inkwell add onTapDown and call startAnimatingElevation

```
startAnimatingElevation(){
  _updatedElevation = 50;
  elevationTimer = Timer.periodic(
  const Duration(milliseconds: 1),
  (timer) {
   if(_updatedElevation > 0)
   {
    _updatedElevation--;
    setState((){});
   }
   else{
     timer.cancel();
    }
  },
);
}
```

assign _updatedElevation as the elevation of the card you wish to animate.

Then add onTapUp in inkwell and reset allvalues.

```
_updatedElevation = 50;
elevationTimer.cancel();
```